# What happens if I change the value of the control register cr0?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, kernel, paging, cpu-registers

I am reading about the Linux Kernel, and I learnt about the `cr0` control register that stores flags about **paging**, **protected mode**, etc.

I was wondering, if it is even possible, what would happen if somehow I managed to change the value of `cr0` to modify flags?

I don't want to ruin something on memory by disabling paging or anything, so I thought about trying myself, but I am afraid of what could happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running kernel code, it is certainly possible (and necessary at boot time) to modify CR0.  Most of the time, modifying it will simply cause your system to crash more or less instantly.

I don't know if that's something worth being "afraid" of--depends on how much you care about rebooting your machine.  You can see all of the things CR0 controls on [this page](https://wiki.osdev.org/CPU_Registers_x86#CR0).  Modifying it will require either modifying the Linux kernel or writing a kernel module.  If you try to access it from userspace code (using inline assembly, for example), then your userspace program will simply encounter a fault and quit, much like what happens if you try reading from an invalid address.

Comment: The sensible way "play around with" it would be using a virtual machine or emulator, e.g. BOCHS has a built-in debugger that lets you single-step a legacy BIOS boot sector.